# How can I boot into Windows 10 DVD from UEFI?

Tags: windows-10, boot, uefi, boot-manager

I have a laptop which has a weird boot issue (the issue is - hopefully - not relevant to this question; and I'll post a Q about it later; but in short, on boot, it goes into Windows Boot Menu with 4 different Windows installations listed, any one of the 4 leads to "installation failed".

When I tried to boot the laptop (Gateway NE 522) with bootable Windows 10 install DVD; it *never booted into DVD* - instead, it showed "Boot Manager" with only HDD "Windows Boot Manager" as an option, when in UEFI mode (the image isn't of my screen but my screen looks nearly identical except for HDD name being different).

[image]

Troubleshooting steps taken:

- I went into BIOS setup and ensured that under UEFI mode, DVD-ROM was the first drive in boot order. No effect.
- However, when I switched from UEFI to Legacy mode, DVD booted without any issue (that didn't help me, since none of recovery options worked; and installing Windows on the correct partition failed since it was GBR partition).

## How can I allow booting into my DVD from UEFI mode?